# How to compile libstdc++ with thread-enable

Tags: compiler-errors, libstdc++

I have compiled libstd++,with flags:

```
../gcc-gcc-5_4_0-release/libstdc++-v3/configure --enable-libstdcxx-threads=yes  --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf   CFLAGS="-funwind-tables" CPPFLAGS="-O2 -g3 -gdwarf-4 -funwind-tables -lpthread" --prefix=`pwd`/install --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs--enable-tls --disable-multilib
```

which I have set --enable-libstdcxx-threads=yes but when use it some error happen.

use static lib

```
undefined reference to `std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl_base>, void (*)())'
```

use share lib

```
symbol _ZNSt6thread15_M_start_threadESt10shared_ptrINS_10_Impl_baseEEPFvvE, version GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It looks like you are linking to the wrong `libstdc++` library, but we can't tell because you didn't provide any useful information. In order for anybody to answer your question you need to provide **much** more information. What commands are you using to compile and link?

Comment: The other possibility is that you're using `gcc` not `g++` and so failing to link to libstdc++ at all. The problem has nothing to do with `--enable-libstdcxx-threads` though.